# Can close voters get messaged when a question is edited?

Tags: feature-request

Simply put - if I submit a close vote on a question, and that question is then significantly improved, I should retract my close vote (or possibly help reopen it if it did eventually get closed before improvements). But right now, I don't have a lot of visibility into when a question is edited. So could people get messages (akin to answers to our questions or comment replies) if someone edits a message we voted to close?

I think that this might help us away from the "close with prejudice" style moderation and a little more towards "prune and cultivate". Thoughts?

(Sorry if this has been brought up before. A quick search only found a question about retracting close votes before close votes could be retracted.)

Comment: Sounds like a solid plan to me.

Comment: I've seen lots of feature requests this at MSE/MSO, all seem to stay ignored. My understanding is SE developers believe that features like this can be covered by [combining favorites with RSS reader](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/15509/165773)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an *official* position on this (as a community manager), but I should mention that you don't need to contact the same people who closed a question to reopen it. If it deserves to be reopened, there's an entire site of users here who can carry that out.

We have to be very cautious about piling into that 'inbox' every possible piece of minutia someone might be involved in. We have some very avid curators on this site, so if I had to come in every morning to sift through potentially dozens-to-hundreds of *"did you know that…"* notices in my inbox, **it might actually push me to *discontinue* that activity.**

I'm not saying that an edit isn't worthy of broader notice, but you have to consider that there is a large contingent of user on this site, so sometimes you have to **spread out some of the responsibility so everything doesn't fall on the most avid few.**

That is just my opinion.